# "run time error 1004 unable to set the hidden property of the range class" when trying to hide/unhide some columns and the sheet is protected

Tags: vba, excel

I have macros to hide and unhide some columns.

The macros work until I apply protection to the sheet.

Any suggestions to come around the obstacle?

```
Sub CLOSEINFO()
'
' CLOSEINFO Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    Columns("B:W").Select
    Range("W1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can unprotect, unhide and then reprotect. Or you could use the UserInterfaceOnly argument to the Protect command.

Comment: Take a look at the options available when protecting the worksheet. Typically it defaults as allowing only Select locked cells and Select unlocked cells. Add Format columns to this and the user or your macro will be able to unhide columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Sub CLOSEINFO()
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.ProtectionType <>"" Then
    'or: IF ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.ProtectionType <> WdNoProtection then
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.Unprotect
    End If
    Columns("B:W").Select
    Range("W1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading 'NOTE!
End Sub
```

NOTE: WdAllowOnlyComments, WdAllowOnlyFormFields, WdAllowOnlyReading, WdAllowOnlyRevisions (options for Protection)